# Stock exchange dataset to use it with deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, stock

I'm learning AI and I want to apply my knowledge in the stock exchange.

Do you know if there is a dataset to start training and testing my algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Huge Stock Market Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/borismarjanovic/price-volume-data-for-all-us-stocks-etfs?)
Historical daily prices and volumes of all U.S. stocks and ETFs

High-quality financial data is expensive to acquire and is therefore rarely shared for free. Here I provide the full historical daily price and volume data for all US-based stocks and ETFs trading on the NYSE, NASDAQ, and NYSE MKT. It's one of the best datasets of its kind you can obtain.

The data (last updated 11/10/2017) is presented in CSV format as follows: Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, OpenInt. Note that prices have been adjusted for dividends and splits.

---

[Top 10 Stock Market Datasets for Machine Learning](https://lionbridge.ai/datasets/top-10-stock-market-datasets-for-machine-learning/#:%7E:text=for%20machine%20learning.-,Stock%20Market%20Datasets,%2C%20NYSE%2C%20and%20NYSE%20MKT.&text=Stock%20Market%20from%20a%20High,%2C%20NASDAQ%2C%20and%20S%26P%20500.)

---

Answer (score 0):

if you using https://rstudio.cloud, install tidyquant package can get the latest and updated real-time dataset...